# Ошибки NetBeans 8.2 IDE

Tags: java, netbeans

Изначально IDE работала нормально, но с некоторых пор почему-то перестала корректно запускаться. Идет загрузка и подклчючение модулей, но после всего NetBeans появляется в процесса + на панели управления появляется иконка, но само окно не работает и его не возможно развернуть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что будет если нажать на кнопку максимайз?

Comment: Roman C, да помогло, что-то и не додумался... Она сразу не появилась. Только при запуске второй IDE появилось дополнительно окно, в котором и оказалась кнопка максимайз.  Впервые такое случилось, что-то даже растерялся)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог совет Roman C, что-то и не додумался до подобного. Только при запуске второй IDE появилось дополнительно окно, в котором и оказалась кнопка максимайз. Впервые такое случилось, что-то даже растерялся)